# Ubuntu will not go to login screen

Tags: boot

I am a new user and i have been using Ubuntu for a couple of weeks now. I shut the computer down yesterday and when i opened it this morning it got stuck at the loading screen with the dots. I tried opening grub by pressing shift and nothing happened. I don't really know what else to do. If anybody could please help me solve this it would be greatly appreciated as i have some important files saved there.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below listed method On start press:

Ctrl + Alt + F1

then type 'startx' (without quotes)